# Handling OS file drop into Tabulator at a specific position

Tags: tabulator

I have a Tabulator table with a list of files which are dropped in from the OS Finder/Explorer etc. All good so far, but as it stands I'm just adding the new rows to the end of the table.

How can I insert the new rows into the table at the place where they were dropped?

I did have a look at the Tabulator internal message bus but it seems all the activity stops when I'm dragging files over the table. Maybe this is because the browser is out of focus?

What I tried - I did come up with something. Every time the table is added to/reordered, I iterate through the rows, getting the DOM element for each. I set an attribute "tableindex" in the DOM element with the row number.

Then in my `dragover` event handler I can do `event.target.parentElement.getAttribute("tableindex")` and get the row number back. I then do some CSS styling on the table row to indicate where the new drop will go.

It's pretty janky though. I'm sure there is a better way than this.